# How can I perform mass provisioning of Debian Guest VMs on XenServer?

Tags: debian, xenserver, automation

There are a number of tools for provisioning physical and virtual servers, but I can't see a well documented solution for provisioning XenServer Debian guests, apart from using XenCenter itself.

With XenCenter guest VM provisioning, we could create a custom template from the specific version of Debian we want to use, specify the install media, and use a Preseed config file to automate the install options. Then once the VM is up and running, we can use some Config / State Management software to whip it in to shape.

However, this is for only deploying one VM at a time. What about provisioning multiple VMs at once, either via the command line, or ideally a web interface?

Comment: Rcvd this response from a Citrix employee on their forum:

You will want to have the Debian Linux VM boot from ethernet. It would be good to post in Debian forums how does one boot Debian off of ethernet to a thin client device. I am sure other Linux distros do this (not just Debian). Once you know the process, then it is a matter of Gust VM on XenServer boot from network. Citrix has a product for Windows (Provisioning Server), so that can give you an idea how it is done. If there is no solution for Linux guest, this may be a good business opportunity if you have the need and the motivation.

Answer (score 0):

There are [xen-tools](http://xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/) for scripted provisioning of Xen DomU guests running Debian, Ubuntu or CentOS, but so far it can only provision one guest per call. It though should be safe to provision multiple guests in parallel, but I never tried that.